# Beautiful Soup get_all() iteration stopping after N results

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The following Python script is running without errors, but is only returning the results for the first 6 malls.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

stores_link = "http://www.ardenfair.com/Directory"

stores_driver = webdriver.Firefox()
stores_driver.get(stores_link)

stores_html = stores_driver.page_source
stores_soup = BeautifulSoup(stores_html, "html5lib")

for outer_stores_html in stores_soup.find_all(class_="result-item uk-scrollspy-init-inview uk-scrollspy-inview uk-animation-fade"):
    try:
        store_name = outer_stores_html.find_all(class_="result-description font-style-4")[0].text
        store_level_phone = outer_stores_html.find_all(class_="search-result-details font-style-1")[0].text

        print("-->" + store_name, store_level_phone)
    except IndexError:
        continue

stores_driver.close()
```

I am looking at the HTML, and the div I am searching for in the find_all() method is identical for every store, and there are way more than 6 on the page.  Why am I only finding the first 6?

Comment: The list is paginated that's why your scrapper only loads the initially loaded items. You can program your selenium driver to scroll down until all the items are loaded. Than start the scrubbing.

Comment: Thanks!  Let me google around with that bit of knowledge, sure I will find something.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because for the animation of `fading in and out`, the css `classes` of HTML elements are changing on the fly. You should only use those classes that do not change. I had a quick look into it and I think you should use the for loop as below:

```
for outer_stores_html in stores_soup.find_all(class_="result-item"):
    try:
        store_name = outer_stores_html.find_all(class_="result-description")[0].text
        store_level_phone = outer_stores_html.find_all(class_="search-result-details")[0].text

        print("-->" + store_name, store_level_phone)
    except IndexError:
        continue
```

Notice the class names I have used for the elements. I used only one for each `find_all()` function.

**Result:**
I got many results (184 results, I think).

Comment: Awesome!  That works... it never dawned on me what the rest of the text was within the "" for class, but I do see the referencing to fading.  Thanks